# Pipe console output of IntelliJ to a script

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

It is possible to pipe the console output of an intellij application to a bash command so I can pretty-print it on the console directly?

I know I can save the log output to a file, but I still want to keep it on the stout window only, but just parse it through a script.

Answer (score 0):

Piping output is a feature of the terminal shell.

IntelliJ IDEA is not using a terminal to run your app, therefore it's not possible with the default Run/Debug configurations.

You could use an external tool that will open a command line shell and run your app there, but the shell has to be open in a separate window and it will not be possible to get the formatted output directly in the IDE.

There is a [related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167330) in YouTrack, but it's unlikely to be implemented soon.